# How to separate development and production in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, devops, cicd

I am developing a Python application to automate my tasks, I would like to have two separate environments, development and production, and in the future maybe a Web app environment or a CLI tool environment.

The development phase for example has modules for unit testing and API keys that I don't want to be shipped to production. Is it possible to have a `package.json` equivalent that can help me?

I also want to define the entry file that has to be executed first, which is `main.py` for my project, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

For package.json equivalents: You can define different `requirements.txt` files for development and production. For example, `requirements.prod.txt` and `requirements.dev.txt`. Inside the dev requirements, you can actually define the prod requirements by placing `-r requirements.prod.txt` inside the `requirements.dev.txt`. This way, development requirements will include all the production packages, plus something else for e.g. testing purposes.

For API keys: I would create a `.ini` file for production and development and take care of only shipping the production version to production. In the code, you can primarily read the development `.ini` file, and only use the production one if development version does not exist. This way it is easier for the `prod.ini` and `dev.ini` config files to coexist in the project folder. When there is no `dev.ini` in production, `prod.ini` will be used.

You can define the entry point in your script by running `python main.py`, please elaborate what you meant with this.

If you need more info, please comment so I can modify my answer.